# Querying MySQL Table for Records where Timestamp is X Weeks After Another

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a MySQL table with two different Timestamp columns: `created` and `lastSent`. I'm looking to query the table and only retrieve records whose `lastSent` timestamp is a certain whole number of weeks ahead of `created`.

```
╔════╦═════════╦══════════╗
║ ID ║ created ║ lastSent ║
╠════╬═════════╬══════════╣
║ 1  ║ Aug 18  ║ Aug 25   ║
╠════╬═════════╬══════════╣
║ 2  ║ Aug 11  ║ Aug 25   ║
╠════╬═════════╬══════════╣
║ 3  ║ Aug 19  ║ Aug 25   ║
╠════╬═════════╬══════════╣
║ 4  ║ Aug 20  ║ Aug 25   ║
╠════╬═════════╬══════════╣
║ 5  ║ Aug 3   ║ Aug 24   ║
╚════╩═════════╩══════════╝
```

For example, the query I'm looking for would give me records 1, 2, and 5, but not 3 and 4.

Thank you so much! I hope I explained this well enough.

Comment: What did you try? please paste your currently non-working query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also write your question as:

> Find the rows where `created` and `lastSent` have the same weekday.

Then the answer would be obvious:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE WEEKDAY(created) = WEEKDAY(lastSent);
```

Comment: Duh...this makes it so obvious. Thank you, Paul

Answer (score 1):

Use the modulus operator to see if the number of days in the difference is a multiple of 7.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE DATEDIFF(created, lastsent) % 7 = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make use of the [datediff](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function to get the number of weeks between the timestamps.

Comment: I'll look into this. Thank you!

Comment: He doesn't care about the number of weeks between them. He just wants to know if it's an exact multiple of a week.

Answer (score 0):

seems you are looking for the rows with a diff with >  1 week

```
select * from my_table  
where ROUND(DATEDIFF(lastSent, created)/7, 0) > 1
```

Comment: That's partially correct! However if `lastSent` is Aug 1 and `created` is Aug 25, I don't want that record either, because it's not a whole number of weeks.

Comment: first :  lastsent 1Aug  and created 25  Aug ??????  second how many week you want for filter ??

Comment: @scaisEdge He's not looking for a specific number of weeks. He wants to test if the difference is a multiple of 7 days.